# Synchronously reading stdin in Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, stdin, synchronous

I've been doing this to synchronously read the whole stdin data under Linux:

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync('/dev/stdin');
```

This obviously won't work on Windows since there is no /dev/stdin file. What could I do to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module readline-sync do the job very well.

```
npm install readline-sync
```

and then:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var answer = readlineSync.question('What is your favorite food? :');
console.log('Oh, so your favorite food is ' + answer);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync

Answer (score 9):

```
var size = fs.fstatSync(process.stdin.fd).size;
var buffer = size > 0 ? fs.readSync(process.stdin.fd, size)[0] : '';
```

Comment: On Node v16.15.0 this gives me
**Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, fstat**