# How to pass data from PHP to Node?

Tags: php, node.js

This is what I'm trying right now:

#### PHP

```
shell_exec('node bin/gfm.js '.escapeshellarg($code))
```

#### Node.js

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

But Node only seems to be receiving the first *line* of `$code`, so it appears that `escapeshellarg` is not escaping newlines correctly.

How else can I do this? I'm fine using `stdin` if that's easier, but it looks complicated on both the PHP and Node side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some fiddling, but I think I got it:

#### PHP

```
$spec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", 'r'),  
    1 => array("pipe", 'w'), 
);

$proc = proc_open('node bin/gfm.js', $spec, $pipes);
fwrite($pipes[0], $code);
fclose($pipes[0]);
$resp = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
proc_close($proc);

echo $resp;
```

#### Node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

var size = fs.fstatSync(process.stdin.fd).size;
var buffer = size > 0 ? fs.readSync(process.stdin.fd, size)[0] : '';

console.log(buffer);
```

credit: [Sigmund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742711/65387)