# How do I read a single character from stdin synchronously?

Tags: node.js

Put in another way, what is the node.js equivalent of C's `getchar` function? (which waits for input and when it gets it, it returns the character code of the letter, and subsequent calls get more characters from stdin)

I tried searching google, but none of the answers were synchronous.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9742711/1048697

Comment: @Bulkan that only works for files being piped into the script. The accepted answer for that question will work better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8452997/893780

Comment: You need to set `stdin.setRawMode(true);` Have a look at this answer for a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506613/771431

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation of getChar based [fs.readSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position):

> fs.readSync(fd, buffer, offset, length)

Unlike the other answer, this will be *synchronous*, only read *one* char from the stdin and be *blocking*, just like the C's `getchar`:

```js
let fs = require('fs')

function getChar() {
  let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1)
  fs.readSync(0, buffer, 0, 1)
  return buffer.toString('utf8')
}

console.log(getChar())
console.log(getChar())
console.log(getChar())
```

Comment: WIth this method, I got following error, any idea?

Error: EAGAIN: resource temporarily unavailable, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:611:3)

Comment: Looks like stdin is not available - I'm assuming you're testing this code in interactive mode (with `node -i`)? It will not work when executed like this, but will work when doing `node script.js` or `echo "input" | node script.js`.

Comment: For me, this indeed reads one char, but only after the user pressed "enter" and stdin contains the entire line. Is there a way to get a char right after the user presses it?